# any way to erase group data-blocks?

Tags: linked-data, outliner, data-blocks

I linked a group and so It's objects to the scene, then saved. Changed idea and deleted. Saved and closed blender. Opened It again and still find this group data-block in the *.blend file.

any way to delete this group? It doesn't let me link one more time that group ... *[yes, I changed idea one more time]*

[image: data-block]

I also have this orphan data that doesn't get deleted after closing blender.. It was on the linked group. Maybe correlated?

[image: orphan]

**UPDATE**

I also made a piece of the imported group, *proxy*. but then has been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by right click on the linked group and then "unlink group".

It was possible only on this tab.

[image: solved]

Comment: You'll find that sometimes you need to save and reload the blend file a few times to get rid of orphaned data.